# Limitar tamanho do array na tela

Tags: python, array

Eu estou trabalhando com dados de uma tabela, mas usei alguns comandos como `numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)` para tentar mostrar todo array sem o (...) que omitem alguns itens.
Mas agora estou querendo inverter isso.
Usei o `df.head(8)` para mostrar apenas o 8 primeiros itens do array, mas ele continua mostrando todos.
Quero voltar para o modelo default onde o `head()` funcione.

Comment: e você usuou o `set_printoptions` de volta, para um valor que te sirva?

Comment: sim, usei o `np.set_printoptions( threshold = 200)` , mas nada aconteceu. o array tem 99 elementos, ele mostra os 30 primeiros, ..., 69 em diante até o 98.

Comment: bom - ocê acaba de se responder - com threshold=200, você diz que o data rame só será reformatado quando você tivermais de 200 linhas. Ponha o threshold em 8 .

Comment: Seria ótimo, mas acabei de testar com =5 e nada mudou, ainda aparecem os 99 itens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você aparentemente está confundindo as coisas - menciona opções do NumPy, mas fala em "tabela", e sua variável tem o nome `df`, que normalmente é usado para dataframes do Pandas (que não é a mesma biblioteca, apesar de fazer uso da mesma).

De qualquer forma temos duas coisas: o método `head`, que existe nos dataframes, retorna o exato número de linhas - então `df.head(8)`, gera 8 linhas, e não mais. Se você está vendo mais dados do que isso, pode ser que cada elemento de seu dataframe sejam outros arrays. Se, por exemplo, dentro do seu dataframe, os items dentro das células são arrays do numpy, as opções de impressão não vão funcionar.

De qualquer forma, enquanto que quantas linhas são mostradas de um numpy.ndarray são configuradas por `numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=...)`, o equivalente para elementos do pandas.DataFrame é

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = ...
```

tanto os limites do numpy como do pandas funcionam a contento - arrays e dataframes com tamanho maior que o limite são resumidos, caso contrário são exibidas por inteiro.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado! Realmente ainda não tenho conhecimento suficiente sobre as bibliotecas e às vezes me confundo. Uso muito material da internet então algo pode ter desconfigurado. 
Obrigado pela ajuda!